# Are the parameters sent from one jsp to another jsp page are saved?

Tags: jsp, parameters

I try to send parameter from menu page to My home page which include both the menu page and the page which comes through a parameter from one href form menu page .
MainPage inside folder in my web app, and all other jsps and the menue inside  AdminPages folder inside the web-inf folder , so when i call AnyPage.jsp from the menu i make
Add new user

and in the MainPage

**THE problem** is that for the fisrt time I press on add new user link it works properly and call it's sevlet but when i click again over it , an exception happen 
The requested resource (/IUG_OSQS_system_web/**Admin/Admin**/MainPage.jsp) is not available.
i think it save **admin** parameter and make something of concatanation ! or other thing which i don't know !!
Can any body help?Here is a picture which could help to get what i mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace links like

```
<a href="Admin/MainPage.jsp">
```

inside the `MainPage.jsp` and all of its include pages by

```
<a href="MainPage.jsp">
```

This problem is in no way related to passing parameters. It's just a misconception of how relative URL's work.

Comment: It's not working too , it makes exception that The requested resource (/IUG_OSQS_system_web/MainPage.jsp) is not available :( and that also is reasonable, i should define the correct url

Comment: You should change this **only** in `MainPage.jsp` and all of its include pages. Not in `AnyPage.jsp` or so. You should interpret `<a>` links as in the request URL context, not in the local disk file system path context.